# Perl Variable Concatenation

Tags: perl

I am trying this code, but the concatenation was not done.

```
$host=qx(hostname -s);
my $day=qx(date +%A);
$fileType="$host-$day.tgz";
print $fileType;
```

When I execute this, I'll get output like, one by one

```
ldap
-Thursday
.tgz
```

But, I need a output like  ***ldap-Thursday.tgz***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qx` returns the string including the final newline. Remove it with [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp):

```
$host = qx{hostname -s};
chomp $host;
```

Note that [Sys::Hostname](http://p3rl.org/Sys::Hostname) provides a `hostname` subroutine which already removes any unwanted whitespace.

Similarly, you can use `localtime->fullday` with [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) instead of calling `date +%A`.